# Convert a string to a swt color

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, swt, awt

The real problem is that I want to use a Color Chooser (for awt color), for a swt component.
So I thought to get the awt color, then do a .toString on it, recover a string, and then convert it into a swt color. But it was harder than I expected.

Here is the string I would like to convert :

```
String myColor = "Color {248, 248, 248}";
```

I did a .toString method on an awt color.

Do you have any idea on how I could do that ?

Comment: SWT has a `ColorDialog` to select colors. JFace also has a `ColorSelector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample method taken from this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Createsaswtcolorinstancetomatchthergbvaluesofthespecifiedawtcoloralphachannelisnotsupported.htm), that converts an *awt* `Color` to a *swt* `Color` :

```
public static Color toSwtColor(Device device, java.awt.Color color) {
        return new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color(device,
                color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue());
    }
```